# How to SET CONVERT date and time formats with MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run the following SQL statement but cant quite get the syntax right..

```
UPDATE [order]
SET [Status] = 'F', [nInvoiceStatus] = 1, [nTotalItemsShipped] = [nTotalItemsOrdered], [Total Lines Shipped] = [Total Lines], 
[Date Order Finished] = CONVERT (VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(),111), CONVERT (VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(),108)
WHERE [Status] = 'N';
```

My objective is to insert the current date and time in the format `'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss'`

Does anyone have any advice or helpful pointers? I am no SQL expert but I am happy to try out alternative solutions or research (I have looked around the net already) if pointed in the right direction.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'??? it seems you have an additional convert `[Date Order Finished] = CONVERT (VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(),111), CONVERT (VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(),108)`. try using `[Date Order Finished] = CONVERT (VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(),111) + ' ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(),108)`

Comment: If you're storing date time data as *strings*, you're doing it wrong - you ought to be using the data types that are provided. If you *are* using the appropriate data types, they don't **have** a format.

Comment: The error was "Incorrect syntax near CONVERT expecting '_', ID, PSEUDOCOL, QUOTED_ID, or VARIABLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try concatenating the Date and Time:

```
[Date Order Finished] = 
      CONVERT (VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(),111) +' '+ CONVERT (VARCHAR(16), GETDATE(),108)
```

Comment: Thank you that was perfect!

Due to limits on the data cell I had to adjust my varchar count but the final code looks like

UPDATE [order]
SET [Status] = 'F', [nInvoiceStatus] = 1, [nTotalItemsShipped] = [nTotalItemsOrdered], [Total Lines Shipped] = [Total Lines], 
[Date Order Finished] = CONVERT (varchar(16), GETDATE(),111) +' '+ CONVERT (varchar(5), GETDATE(),108)
WHERE [Status] = 'N';

and the output was:

2014/11/11 12:57